# rsync cron job with a password?

Tags: rsync, cron, cronjob

I want to set up an rsync command as a cron job, so I need to find a way to supply my server password automatically to rsync.

Currently I have a shell script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync *.rss me@myserver.com:/home/dir --password-file ~/rsync.password
```

The `rsync.password` file just contains my password.

However, when I run the script, I get:

```
The --password-file option may only be used when accessing an rsync daemon.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1241) [sender=3.0.7]
```

Could anyone let me know how to fix this, so I can start to run the shell script as a cron job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you really want to do is look at setting up public keys between the servers so they 'trust' each other and passwords are not needed.

Have a read here:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/rsync-over-ssh-without-password/

http://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and

Comment: That links do not solve the problem when executing under cron.daily, it runs without password in a Termina

Answer (score 1):

Some times there is need to rsync without ssh involved, especially if rsync is running as a server on one side. 
In this case I wrote instructions, how to give rsync password from command line.

This is very good for scripting:
[rsync-without-prompt-for-password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111526/rsync-without-prompt-for-password/186224#186224)